# After migrate on PHP7.x simpleXML give "Node no longer exists"

Tags: php, xml, parsing, php-7

I try migrate from php5.6 to php7.x but i have problem with read xml.

If I run this code on php5.6 work without problem, on php7.x some strange error

```
    echo 'LIBXML_VERSION ' . LIBXML_VERSION . "\n";
echo 'LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION ' . LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION . "\n";
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);


 $entryContent ='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0"
                         xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0"
                         xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0"
                         xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0"
                         xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0"
                         xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0"
                         xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
                         xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
                         xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0"
                         xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0"
                         xmlns:presentation="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:presentation:1.0"
                         xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0"
                         xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0"
                         xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0"
                         xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
                         xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0"
                         xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0"
                         xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office"
                         xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer"
                         xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc"
                         xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
                         xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
                         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                         xmlns:field="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooxml-odf-interop:xmlns:field:1.0"
                         office:version="1.1">
    <office:scripts/>
    <office:body>
        <office:spreadsheet>
            <table:table table:name="Data">
            <table:table-column table:style-name="co0"/>
            <table:table-column table:style-name="co0"/>
            <table:table-column table:style-name="co0"/>

            <table:table-row>
                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="Mar 16, 2017">
                <text:p>Mar 16, 2017</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>
                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="2.0E">
                <text:p>2.0E</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>
            </table:table-row>

            <table:table-row>
                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="id"
                    table:style-name="ceHeader">
                <text:p>id</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>

                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="tag1"
                    table:style-name="ceHeader">
                <text:p>tag1</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>

                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="tag2"
                    table:style-name="ceHeader">
                <text:p>tag2</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>
            </table:table-row>

            <table:table-row>
                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="8d427c81bae5a27d07fa2d68eb348fbdd8e83571">
                <text:p>8d427c81bae5a27d07fa2d68eb348fbdd8e83571</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>
                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="1">
                <text:p>1</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>
                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="0">
                <text:p>0</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>
            </table:table-row>

            <table:table-row>
                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="e04913657b418d19838b920bc379fea9c4b7c76a">
                <text:p>e04913657b418d19838b920bc379fea9c4b7c76a</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>
                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="0">
                <text:p>0</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>
                <table:table-cell office:value-type="string"
                    office:value="1">
                <text:p>1</text:p>
                </table:table-cell>
            </table:table-row>

            </table:table>
        </office:spreadsheet>
    </office:body>
</office:document-content>
 ';
 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($entryContent, 'SimpleXMLElement');
if ($xml === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML\n";
    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
        echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
}

$ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
$spreadsheetXml = $xml->children($ns['office'])->{'body'}->{'spreadsheet'};

$headerRowXml = $spreadsheetXml->children($ns['table'])->{'table'}->{'table-row'}->{1};
print_r($headerRowXml);
print_r($headerRowXml->children($ns['table'])->{'table-cell'}->{1}->children($ns['text'])->{0});
print_r(libxml_get_errors());
```

I got this output and error

> LIBXML_VERSION 20904
>
> LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION 2.9.4

SimpleXMLElement Object
(
)

> Warning: main(): Node no longer exists in test4.php on line 122
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function children() on null in test4.php:122

On php5.6 i got

```
    LIBXML_VERSION 20902
LIBXML_DOTTED_VERSION 2.9.2
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [table-cell] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [style-name] => ceHeader
                        )

                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [style-name] => ceHeader
                        )

                )

            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [style-name] => ceHeader
                        )

                )

        )

)
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [0] => tag1
)
Array
(
)
```

How this fix to work in php7.x?

Comment: install `php7.0-xml` package and restart your server

Comment: Package php71w-xml-7.1.2-1.w6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do

Comment: I find solution replace {'table-row'}->{1} with {'table-row'}[1] work on php7 and php5.6